# Ошибки при запуске бота на Python

Tags: python

При запуске бота вылазит ошибка, и это почти у каждого бота также при запуске

```js
PS C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\tg bot\Бот автопродажа 2.0 (рассылки + инструкция по установке)> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\tg bot\Бот автопродажа 2.0 (рассылки + инструкция по установке)\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import config, dop, payments, adminka, files
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\tg bot\Бот автопродажа 2.0 (рассылки + инструкция по установке)\dop.py", line 3, in <module> 
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'
```

Comment: У вас случайно нет файла с именем telebot.py? Если есть, то переименуйте

Comment: А как и где я могу его найти? В самом проекте нету такого файла

Comment: Добавьте после импорта `telebot` такую строку `print(telebot.__file__)` и посмотрите, что выведет.

Comment: S C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\AutoShop> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\AutoShop\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from telebot  import types, apihelper
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 12, in <module>
    from telebot import util
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 322, in <module>
    def user_link(user: types.User, include_id: bool=False) -> str:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'telebot.types' has no attribute 'User' (most likely due to a circular import)
Опять ошибка с теле